# Covert Elapsed time to datetime

Tags: excel, pandas, datetime, elapsedtime

I have an excel file that contains the start date: 24/09/2021, start time: 16:13:48, The Test Length [D:H:M]: 06:17:25.

The data are saved for PM in Elapsed time after the start time every 5 minutes.
[image]

I would like to convert this Elapsed time to DateTime(24/09/2021  16:18:00), considering the start time and start date either in pandas or Excel for the whole test duration as below

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `origin` and `unit` parameters:

```
df['Elapsed Time [s]'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Elapsed Time [s]'],
                                        origin='24/09/2021 16:13:48',
                                        unit='s')
```